# How to add css tag to SideBarPanel in Shiny App (R)

Tags: r, shiny

I want to change the background color of the sideBarPanels on my page in my shiny app....but...only on one specific page.  So I am thinking of using CSS tags but am unsure how to do it.

I tried this:

```
sidebarPanel(class="set1",   
htmlOutput("vizTest")
)
```

And then tried referencing the class in the CSS file:

```
#set1 form.well { 
background: transparent;
border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: `.set1` would be enough to reference the class `set1`

Comment: yeah I tried that too.  I think I need some kind of tag$

Answer (score 6):

So the trick was to wrap the sidebarPanel in a div and then set the class for the div.  Then it can be referenced in the usual manner using the '.' prefix:

ui.R

```
div(class="set1",
sidebarPanel(

#content of panel here

))
```

css file

```
.set1 form.well { 
background: transparent;
border: 0px;
}
```

Comment: It's also possible to do this without wrapping the sidebar ui in a div by directly accessing the sidebar via `.form.well {some CSS here}` in your CSS-script. Althought using div is probably little bit better concerning code clarity?